# Probability of drawing a pair from a poker hand, unordered with replacement?

Tags: combinatorics

I am wondering what is the probability with which you can draw a pair in a 5-card hand from a standard 52-card deck, if order does not matter in the context of cards in the hand, and if the cards can be replaced with every draw?

Comment: $\binom{52}{5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the probability of a one-pair hand, it will be easier if we take the order of drawing into account. It is true that all we care about is what hand we end up with. But taking order into account will get us the right answer without the need to look at special cases.

There are $52^5$ **equally likely** sequences of $5$ cards. We count the number of $5$-card **sequences** that satisfy the "one pair" condition. Counting "hands" will not work unless we are very careful, for not all hands are equally likely.

The two **locations** in the draw where the  pair will be  can be chosen in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. Once we have chosen the two locations, the **kind** we have two of can be chosen in $13$ ways. Once we have done that, the leftmost chosen "pair" location can be filled in $4$ ways, and for each such way we can fill the other pair location in $4$ ways, for a total of $4^2$.

Now it is time to deal with the remaining $3$ positions. There are $48$ ways to fill the leftmost empty position. For each of these, we can fill the next position in $44$ ways, and then the last position can be filled in $40$ ways.

The number of one-pair sequences is therefore 
$$\binom{5}{2}(13)(4^2)(48)(44)(40).$$
Divide by $52^5$ for the probability.

**Remark:** We interpreted "the cards can be replaced at every draw" to mean that the drawn card *is* replaced in the deck before the next draw. So the model is that we draw a card, record its value, replace and shuffle, doing this a total of $5$ times. We want the probability that among the $5$ recorded cards, there are exactly two cards (possibly identical) of one kind, and $3$ useless cards all of different kinds.

Comment: You are welcome. The possibility of identical cards means that a "hands" based analysis would be very painful.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "hands" vs. "5-card sequences"?

Comment: A five-card sequence is *ordered*.  A hand is a set of cards, in this case not quite a set, it is what is often called a **multiset**, since cards can repeat. In order to calculate the probability, it is quite a bit easier to work with sequences than with multisets. It *could* be done with multisets, and we would get the same probability, but the calculation becomes more painful and more error-prone.

Comment: Ok, interesting. But why would we get the **same** probability?

Comment: Because it is the same problem, so any two correct solutions will yield the same numerical answer. I have solved the problem of finding the probability that a **hand** is a $1$-pair hand. For technical reasons, mainly to get a sample space in which all outcomes are equally likely, i found it more convenient to use a counting argument on *ordered* hands.

Comment: No. Let's take a simple, maybe too simple, example. Have $8$ balls, $5$ white and $3$ black. We remove $3$ balls, selected at random. What is the probability of $3$ white? One way, unordered, standard, get $\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{0}/\binom{8}{3}$. Now ordered: In order, can pick balls in $(8)(7)(6)$ ways. In order, can pick $3$ white in $(5)(4)(3)$ ways. Divide. We get the same numerical answer as in the first way.

Comment: Ok got it thanks.

Comment: Something about 5C2 doesn't seem right. Poker hand has only 5 cards so this does not seem like a strange result, however this is with replacement. We can keep drawing cards.

At higher numbers like say 500 probability will far exceed 1

Answer (score -1):

"There are 52<sup>5</sup> equally likely sequences of 5 cards." This is already erroneous. We have 52 possibilities for the 1st card, but this leaves only 51 for the next choice, 50 for the next choice, and so on. So there are 52*51*50*49*48 possible 5-card draws.

Other errors are also present.

Comment: The OP said cards *are* replaced after every draw, so there are $52^5$ possible sequences.